# Generating weighted intervals in Python

Tags: python, random, scipy, weighted

I know how to produce a weighted integer with `random.choice`.

Now I have 5000 integers from 0 to 1000. I want to have say 75% to land in the inerval 0-500, 20% 501-750 and 5% between 751-1000. What I tried and failed is

`x = random.choice([np.arange(501), np.arange(501,751), np.arange(751, 1001)], size=5000, p=[0.75, 0.2, 0.05])`

But then I only get random aranged intervals. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Simply pick 5000 * 0.75 from range(501), ..., and so on

Comment: @DaniMesejo but them should I use `choice`, and then can I have for instance first a number lower than 500, then larger then again smaller.

Comment: You can shuffle it afterwards

Comment: you can use shuffle https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.choice(list(range(1001)), size=5000, p=
[.75/501]*501+[.2/250]*250+[.05/250]*250)
```

Comment: and why is `p=[.75/501]*501...` is necessary, why shouldnt `p=[.75]*501...` suffice?

Comment: if you read the documentation on np.random.choice, it says the following for the parameter 'p': "The probabilities associated with *each* entry in a. If not given the sample assumes a uniform distribution over all entries in a." 

So p needs to state each distinct possibility for every value in the list [0,1....999,1000].

Comment: Additionally, the probabilities in p need to sum to 1; so if you did p=[.75]*501, you would get an error

Answer (score 0):

another version would be:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

N = 5000
probs = [0.75, 0.2, 0.05]
breaks = [0, 501, 751, 1001]

# figure out how big each group should be
sizes = stats.multinomial.rvs(N, probs)

# get values for each group
x = np.concatenate([
  stats.randint.rvs(l, h, size=n)
  for n, l, h in zip(sizes, breaks, breaks[1:])])

# mix everything up
np.random.shuffle(x)
```

some differences to rocket's solution:

- less/smaller temporary variables and more opportunity for vectorisation
- allows probabilities to take irrational values
- the runtime is doesn't depend on the number of possible values generated